# Set Value To 0.00 If Number Goes Negative

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have build this simple rent affordability java-script calculator and the issue that I have is the last box the "Rent Affordability TextBox" can sometime return a - (negative number) Im trying to set that value to 0.00 if number goes negative.

I have add this to my script:

```
if (RentAffordability < 0) RentAffordability = 0.00;
```

with no luck. here is the complete code:

```html
<html lang="en-us">
<head></head>
<body>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function run() {
      var PercentageRate = 40;
      var Income = parseInt(document.getElementById('YearlyIncome').value);
      var Expenses = parseInt(document.getElementById('MonthlyExpenses').value);
      var PercentageCalculated = Income / PercentageRate;

      //document.getElementById('RentAffordability').value = PercentageCalculated - Expenses;
      $('#RentAffordability').val((PercentageCalculated - Expenses).toFixed(2));
    }

    if (RentAffordability < 0) 
      RentAffordability = 0.00;
  </script>
  <script>
    (function($) {
      $.fn.currencyInput = function() {
        this.each(function() {
          var wrapper = $("<div class='currency-input' />");
          $(this).wrap(wrapper);
          $(this).change(function() {
            var min = parseFloat($(this).attr("min"));
            var max = parseFloat($(this).attr("max"));
            var value = this.valueAsNumber;
            if (value < min)
              value = min;
            else if (value > max)
              value = max;
            $(this).val(value.toFixed(2));
          });
        });
      };
    })(jQuery);

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input.currency').currencyInput();
    });
  </script>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Combined Annual Income: </td>
        <td><input type="number" class="currency textBox" name="YearlyIncome" id="YearlyIncome" value="0.00" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Combined Monthly Expenses:</td>
        <td><input type="number" class="currency textBox" name="MonthlyExpenses" id="MonthlyExpenses" value="0.00" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Your Rent Affordability:</td>
        <td><input type="number" class="currency textBox" name="RentAffordability" id="RentAffordability" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="padding-left: 250px;"><button onclick="run()">Calculate Your Rent</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `if` statement needs to be placed *within* the `run()` function.  At the moment you're only checking it when the page loads. You also don't appear to actually ever set a value to `RentAffordability`. I'd also suggest attaching that logic using a jQuery event handler instead of an outdated `onclick` attribute.

Comment: ...you need to set the negative value to 0.00 **before** putting it in the input, obviously. jQuery will not magically change the textbox content after you changed the variable you happened to put in there.

Comment: Also, don't use an `<input>` for output. Use a `<p>` or a `<span>`.

Comment: adding to the above comments- looks like you need to check `if((PercentageCalculated - Expenses) < 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some problems i found

- your if statement is outside of the run function
- you set the RentAffordability before checking if goes negative
- you never create the variable RentAffordability (that i assume it should be the input tag with name/id RentAffordability)

updating your code should be like this:

```
function run() {
   var PercentageRate = 40;
   var Income = parseInt(document.getElementById('YearlyIncome').value);
              var Expenses = parseInt(document.getElementById('MonthlyExpenses').value);
   var PercentageCalculated = Income / PercentageRate;
   var RentAffordability = PercentageCalculated - Expenses
   if (RentAffordability < 0) 
      RentAffordability = 0.00;
   $('#RentAffordability').val((RentAffordability).toFixed(2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `RentAffordability = Math.max(0, RentAffordability)` to get bigger of 0 or current value of RentAffordability.

That way when RentAffordability is negative it will fallback to 0

Comment: Just curious, is this any better than what OP tried? `if (RentAffordability < 0) RentAffordability = 0.00;`

Comment: Justinas, added that an number still goes negative

Comment: May run on Chrome Dev Tools but code I posted don't run in browser

Comment: I honestly don't know where `RentAffordability` is defined, but I changed it to a [working example](http://jsbin.com/moloqiwocu/1/edit)